# Display spin buttons (up down) in ionic

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to show spin buttons(up-down) in my application. In browser it is displayed but cannot see on android application. Ionic framework.

Comment: Show your code which you tried?

Comment: Can you also explain what have you tried so far and where do you need help?

Comment: Thank you guys for your concern. Problem solved. :)